# Testing Tool for UI Style Guides?

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, design-guidelines, ui-guidelines

I was wondering if there are any tools out there for testing an application's conformance to a given graphical style guide? Preferrably cross-technology (Web, Silverlight, Java, etc) but I'd be happy for any pointers (even research tools).

To be clear: I am *NOT* interested in classical "user interface testing" where you (essentially) record mouse clicks and test that the UI behaves as expected. What I am looking for is a tool where you can specify stuff like "Cancel buttons are always on the lower right of a window", "Every OK button is always to the left of a Cancel button", "Background color for all UI widgets is gray", "BUttons have a 1 pt black border" and so on.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a (commercial) tool named "expecco" which might be able to do that for you. It will probably not do that kind of stuff "out of the box", but need some (graphical) programming, though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! From the website it doesn't look as if it supports style guide testing out of the box (as you mentioned), but I wrote their sales people my question. I will add a comment to let you know their response.